# How to keep a 1 to 1 relation consistent

Tags: java, relationship, consistency

Consider the following code in `Lecturer.java`. The setter in `Lecture.java` has the exact same form. Please also note that the attribute of interest is `private`.

```
public void setLecture(Lecture lecture) {
    if (this.lecture == lecture) return;

    if (this.lecture != null) {
        this.lecture.setLecturer(null);
    }

    this.lecture = lecture;

    if (this.lecture != null) {
        this.lecture.setLecturer(this);
    }
}
```

This results in an infinite loop when trying to set a `null` value that has previously not been `null`.

I can't believe it's this hard to keep a 1:1 relation consistent - but I just can't figure out how to do so. How would one solve this issue?

Comment: @Ogen The attribute is supposed to be private.

Comment: Since there is a setter I suppose there is also a getter, right?

Comment: @giannischristofakis Yessir.

Comment: Just a crazy thought, why don't you make the lectures and the lecturers immutable, and keep their relation integrity into a another class?

Comment: @giannischristofakis How would that work? Can you maybe post a code snippet?

Answer (score 0):

Finally, here's your solution:

```
public class A {
    private B b;

    public void setB(B b) {
        if(this.b != null) {
            this.b.unsetA();
        }
        this.b = b;
        if(b != null && b.getA() != this) {
            this.b.setA(this);
        }
    }

    public void unsetB() {
        this.b = null;
    }

    public B getB() {
        return b;
    }

}

public class B {
    private A a;

    public void setA(A a) {
        if(this.a != null) {
            this.a.unsetB();
        }
        this.a = a;
        if(a != null && a.getB() != this) {
            this.a.setB(this);
        }
    }

    public void unsetA() {
        this.a = null;
    }

    public A getA() {
        return a;
    }

}
```

My Test Class:

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String ... args) {
        A a1 = new A();
        B b1 = new B();
        A a2 = new A();
        B b2 = new B();

        checkForZeroOrTwoRelations(a1, a2, b1, b2);
        a1.setB(b1);
        checkForZeroOrTwoRelations(a1, a2, b1, b2);     
        b1.setA(a2);
        checkForZeroOrTwoRelations(a1, a2, b1, b2);
        b2.setA(a2);
        checkForZeroOrTwoRelations(a1, a2, b1, b2);
        b2.setA(null);
        checkForZeroOrTwoRelations(a1, a2, b1, b2);
    }

    private static void checkForZeroOrTwoRelations(A a1, A a2, B b1, B b2) {
        int i = 0;
        if(a1.getB() != null) i++;
        if(a2.getB() != null) i++;
        if(b1.getA() != null) i++;
        if(b2.getA() != null) i++;
        if(i != 0 && i != 2) {
            throw new IllegalStateException();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This one results in an infinite loop as well.

Comment: Come on, you don't really want to make that a public method, do you?

Comment: Yeah.. no. Not really `:D` You could make it private and use an additional public method for that, I'll post an example in a minute.

Comment: This wouldn't work either, because the Lecture's setLecturer(Lecturer, boolean) would be private too. :/

Comment: It should work, at least my Eclipse doesn't complain. And I've posted another solution, which doesn't involve the setter.

Comment: I feel like you've messed the classes up a bit? There's a relation between Lecture and Lecturer.

Comment: Oh sorry, I thought it was the same class. I'll remove my answer and try to figure out something else.

Answer (score 0):

You only have to set the object property to *null* in order to break the infinite loop. But first you have to store the previous value to a temporary variable. It will stop at the first `if` statement, where `null` equals `null`.

```
public void setLecture(Lecture lecture) {

    if (this.lecture == lecture) {
        return;
    }

    if (this.lecture != null) {

        Lecture pastLecture = this.lecture;
        this.lecture = null;

        pastLecture.setLecturer(null);

        pastLecture = null;

    }

    this.lecture = lecture;

    if (lecture != null) {
        lecture.setLecturer(this);
    }
}
```

[**Gist**](https://gist.github.com/giannosfor/f683b823e80f2c36e126)

Answer (score 0):

*I post it as a different answer cause actually I think, my first answer is what you are looking for.*

As for my proposal, you can create a two way map (alternatively you can use [Guava HashBiMap](https://google-collections.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/HashBiMap.html)) to ensure the relation integrity.

```
Map<Lecturer, Lecture> lecturerMap = new HashMap();
Map<Lecture, Lecturer> lectureMap = new HashMap();

public void addRelation(Lecturer lecturer, Lecture lecture) {

    this.checkIntegrity(lecturerMap,lectureMap, lecturer, lecture);
    this.checkIntegrity(lectureMap, lecturerMap, lecture, lecturer);

    lecturerMap.put(lecturer, lecture);
    lectureMap.put(lecture, lecturer);
}

private <T,V> void checkIntegrity(Map<T,V> mapf, Map<V,T> maps, T t, V v) {
    if (mapf.containsKey(t)) {
        V value = mapf.get(t);

        if (maps.containsKey(value)) {
            maps.remove(value);
        }

        mapf.remove(t);
    }
}
```

For sure there are more sophisticated ways to do, but this work as well.

[**Gist**](https://gist.github.com/giannosfor/c0f7a8252c363bad40c2)